# Runtime Error Crime at Piccadily Circus (SPOJ)

Tags: c++

I have written the code for the problem http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PICAD/ as follows

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int T=10;
//int T=1;
while(T--)
{
int p,k;
cin>>p>>k;
int n;
cin>>n;

int *A;
int *B;
A= new int[k+1];
B= new int[k+1];

for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
{A[i]=0;B[i]=0;}
while(n--)
    {
    int start,end;
    cin>>start>>end;

    if(start<p && end>=p && end<k) {A[p]++;B[end]++;}
    else if(start<p && end>=k){A[p]++;B[k]++;}

    else if (start>=p && end <k){A[start]++;B[end]++;}
    else if(start>=p && end >=k){A[start]++;B[k]++;}

    }
int num=0;
int max=A[p]-B[p];
int min=A[p]-B[p];
for(int i=p;i<=k;i++)
{
num=num+A[i];
if(max<num)max=num;
if(min>num)min=num;
num=num-B[i];
}

cout<<min<<" "<<max<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that is always giving "runtime error (SIGABRT)" according to SPOJ which I am unable to understand or correct.
I am frustrated with this for quite some time now.
Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide us with some more details about the problem? Have you narrowed it down to a specific part of the program? Have you tried breaking this down into separate functions, and dissecting pieces of your code to make sure that each piece works as you believe it should?

Comment: Thanks Sir. The problem is that the code works perfectly on my machine with sample test cases and some higher range inputs which I made up. On my machine, I am not facing any runtime errors and thus am not able to debug the code. But SPOJ reports a runtime error. I have tried changing the arrays into vector to see if there was a problem with the memory allocation but again SPOJ reports the same error while it works perfectly well on  my machine. Thanks!

Comment: One way to debug "remotely" might be to insert assertions, that let you determine how far the program managed to get. Or just assert each index before each access. - You could also replace dynamic arrays with `std::vector`, and use the `at` method for element access. This would reliably inform you of out-of-bound accesses, which you might be getting away with on your machine. - After the program has been debugged, you might replace `at` with `[]` for speed.

Comment: Try deleting the arrays A, B, after each test case.

Comment: I tried that. Still gives the same error.

Answer (score -1):

With XCode 4.2.1 on Mac the program works fine for the example input and expected output. I paste in

```
5 10
4
1 8
5 8
7 10
8 9
```

and get

```
1 4
```

If you are getting errors, try using a debugger to find out where exactly the program fails. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using C++ (g++ 4.3.2). The problem is that I am not getting any errors on my machine but SPOJ reports this runtime error.